# Tensorflow install on Mac fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, canopy

I am getting the following problem (command and messages). I am using the Canopy IDE for my Python programming.  Is that what could be causing the problem? Any ideas on what I am missing.  Thanks.

```
Arun
================
MacBook:~ AGupta$ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
Using base prefix '/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.7.4.3348.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents'
New python executable in /Users/AGupta/tensorflow/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/AGupta/tensorflow/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable /Users/AGupta/tensorflow/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/Users/AGupta' (should be u'/Users/AGupta/tensorflow')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Canopy package manager, install or update to the latest available versions of these packages:

funcsigs, mock, protobuf, wheel, numpy

Then open a Canopy Terminal window (from the Canopy Tools menu) and type:

`pip install tensorflow`

To confirm the message that you received: virtualenv is not compatible with Canopy 1.x, which uses venv-based virtual environments baked in. Canopy 2.x returns to flat (non-virtual) environments, leaving you able to use either venv or virtualenv only when you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have downloaded/upgraded all the packages mentioned.  However, when I run the "pip install tensorflow" command I get the following error.  Ideas/suggestions?         Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow